# Problemas migrar proyecto en Django 1.6 a la version Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

Tengo serios problemas para hacer andar mi proyecto en una version de Django mas nueva ( de la 1.6 a la 1.7)

Estoy trabajando con un entorno virtual en el cual reinstale todas las aplicaciones de mi proyecto (desde mi archivo requirements.txt), excepto la version de Django == 1.7 (que sustituí por la anterior)

Si alguien sabe porque puede ocurrir esto, se lo agradecería me ayude

```
ERROR
===============================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\tastypie\models.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tastypie.compat import AUTH_USER_MODEL
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\tastypie\compat.py", line 14, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 136, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "C:\VENVs\qty_v4\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
===============================================================================
```

Answer (score 3):

Asegúrate de que no sea un problema con los [WSGI scripts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/releases/1.7/#wsgi-scripts). En versiones anteriores se usaba así:

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Tienes que modificarlo para que cumpla con la versión actualizada:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Lo que también puedes intentar es llamar al método [`django.setup()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) para registrar tus aplicaciones. Tienes que llamarlo desde el script que te está dando problema que en tu caso sería desde el `manage.py`:

```
# ...

import django
django.setup()

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```